# grab a lunch or grab lunch?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

So I was writing an essay and want to know which sentence is correct-

I'll **grab a lunch** with Prof. Unknown and discuss his research on wearable computational fabrics. Or I'll **grab lunch** with Prof. Unknown and discuss his research on wearable computational fabrics.